# How to execute an action on items filtered out with Where?

Tags: c#, linq

In the codebase where I work, there are a lot of code like this:

```
foreach (var item in itemList)
{
    if (someCondition(item))
    {
        Logger.Error($"Oops, {item} is wrong!");
        continue;
    }

    if (someOtherCondition(item))
    {
        Logger.Error($"Bad thing: {item} is wrong!");
        continue;
    }

    // do the stuff
}
```

Using Linq to filter is more readable, but I also need a readable way to log when each item is filtered out. The [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) extension does not have such a facility. What should I use?

Comment: why do you feel that LINQ would be the appropriate solution here? What's wrong with the solution you have? What is it that you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: LINQ is for queries. The code above doesn't appear to be performing any kind of query.

Comment: morelinq has [`ForEach`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#foreach).

Comment: @JonathanWood `Where` is the equivalent of `filter` in functional languages, isn't it? I want to use `foreach (var item in itemList.Where(someCondition).Where(someOtherCondition))`. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Well, i think you already replied to your own question then. Just use `foreach (var item in itemList.Where(someCondition == true && someOtherCondition == true)`

Comment: Do the conditions need to reference the item for your specific problem? I feel we can help better if more info is given about the specifics of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Uhm if you need to do conditions and then continue with other conditions (if true), i think you are doing fine already. I don't see why you should use linq to filter a list with multiple condition every time you need to check something new.

Comment: @Boiethios: Yes, `where` is the equivalent of a filter, but I didn't see where you were using `where` here. I guess it wasn't clear to me what *do the stuff* was doing./

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to filter the items (create a new items without the error items) and do the logging in one go, you could combine the delegate inside the `Where` (although performing actions inside a predicate is sometimes frowned upon)

```
var newList = itemList.Where(item =>
{
    string err;
    if(someCondition(item))
        err = $"Oops, {item} is wrong!";
    else if(someOtherCondition(item))
        err = $"Bad thing: {item} is wrong!";
    else
        return true; //no error -> return true to include in list
    Logger.Error(err);
    return false;
});
```

---

You could also do a lot with helper functions. Which would be most fitting really depends on the general use case. For example, if `somecondition` is a global function it could log the error itself.

If the conditions and error logs are produced on the fly, you can also use a global helper function such as:

```
public static bool CheckValid<T>(T value, Func<T,bool> ErrorWhen, Func<T,string> GetError)
{
    if(!ErrorWhen(value))return true;
    Logger.Error(GetError(value));
    return false;
}
```

Then chaining and filtering could be done with:

```
newList = itemList.Where(item => CheckValid(item , someCondition, i => $"Oops, {i} is wrong!" ))
        .Where(item => CheckValid(item , someOtherCondition, i => $"Bad thing: {i} is wrong!"));
```

(NB, regardless of which option, the filtering and subsequent logging will only take place if the result is actually enumerated)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do the logging from inside the `Where` predicate:

```
foreach (var item in itemList.Where(delegate (ItemType x) { if (someCondition(x)) { Logger.Error("oops, {x} is wrong!"); return false; } return true; })
                             .Where(delegate (ItemType y) { if (someOtherCondition(y)) { Logger.Error($"Bad thing: {y} is wrong!"); return false; } return true; }))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Although I've shown an example using anonymous delegates, you may prefer to use real, named methods.  It really depends on whether you need to capture variables or the conditions are static.

Comment: I should have thought of that... This is definitely more readable than nested tests/select/casts + tests/whatever. Maybe you are right, I should use named method, thank you.

Comment: delegate can simply be replaced with `() =>` even so, this looks like a nightmare to read.

Answer (score 1):

While you could squeeze all of the logic into the LINQ statements, it's starts looking messy and becomes less readable than your code. I find it cleaner to use subroutines that perform the additional tasks like this:

```
var results = itemList.Where(i => CheckSomeCondition(i) && CheckSomeOtherCondition(i));

bool CheckSomeCondition(T item)
{
    if (someCondition(item))
    {
        Logger.Error($"Oops, {item} is wrong!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool CheckSomeOtherCondition(T item)
{
    if (someOtherCondition(item))
    {
        Logger.Error($"Bad thing: {item} is wrong!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems that your title isn't quite matching your content.  If I wrote code based on your question title

> How to execute an action on items filtered out with Where?

It's seems that the best course is to Filter and return a result **at the same time** log filtered out items.  Encapsulating that is very important.  Otherwise you could accidentally add additional where clauses in between a filter and the logging.

Assume:

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public Person(string name)
  {
    Name = name;
  }
}

public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
  public static List<T> WhereWithFiltered<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values
    ,Func<T, bool> predicate
    ,Action<IEnumerable<T>> filteredAction)
  {
    var result = values.Where(predicate).ToList();
    var filtered = values.Except(result);
    filteredAction(filtered);
    return result;
  }    
}

public void Log(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
  foreach (var item in items)
  {
    Logger.Error($"Bad thing: {item} is wrong!");
  }
}
```

example:

```
var people = new List<Person>
{
  new Person("Frank"),
  new Person("John"),
  new Person("Joe")
};

var filteredPeople = people
  .WhereWithFiltered(p => p.Name.StartsWith("J"), (filtered) => Log(filtered))
  .WhereWithFiltered(p => Condition1(p), (filtered) => Log(filtered))
  .WhereWithFiltered(p => Condition2(p), (filtered) => Log(filtered));
```